# Does a subspace’s dimension tell you how much space it occupies?

Tags: linear-algebra

To what extent does the dimension of a subspace tell you how “big” it is in the ambient space?

For example, for a practical problem, consider a linear system with more equations than unknowns. So, an $m \times n$ matrix, with $m > n$. We might also suppose that we have full rank, so the dimension of the column space is $n$. What can we say about the equation $Ax = b$? Are there almost always solutions? Almost always no solutions? Or something else? If we picked a random $b$ (assuming “random” even makes sense in this context), what are the chances that $Ax = b$ is soluble?

The answer to the above question for $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ is: the column space is a plane, so in fact $Ax = b$ is almost never soluble, because a plane basically occupies zero space in $\mathbb{R}^3$. So this seems a little “paradoxical” to me, in the sense that the dimension is 2 (out of a maximum possible of 3), but we barely occupy any space. I would appreciate some intuition or reasoning about this, and what it is that a subspace’s dimension can be useful for (practically or theoretically), or what it tells us.

Comment: So it's paradoxical that a flat plane in three-dimensional space has zero volume?

Comment: I realize my question has an obvious answer: "no", in the sense that, say, a plane obviously doesn't occupy much space in 3D space. I guess my question is more about... how is it useful for when studying solutions to linear systems (for example)?

Comment: @AnginaSeng I see what you are saying, but my remark about things being paradoxical was more so rhetorical/suggestive. Specifically, I find it interesting that if the dimension is anything less than the entire space, it makes the difference between covering all of the points versus almost none of the points.

Comment: So for example, for someone who didn't know anything about linear algebra, they might naively think that dimension tells you something about space occupied, but this is actually quite the opposite. So maybe a pedagogical question would be: how do we explain this intuitively to students (and motivate the study of what "dimension" is good for)?

Comment: Dimension *does* tell you a bit about the space occupied, you just have to use the appropriate measure (*coughs and mutters about there being a distinct Lebesgue Measure on $\mathbb R^n$ for each $n \in \mathbb N$*). Less tangentially, note that vector spaces are lattices: if you extend at "all" in a new direction, you have to extend "all the way" in that direction; e.g, if you extend your flat plane to have any "height" then it must fill up the whole space. Vector space dimension isn't meant to capture a notion of size in the manner you ask for (that's what measure theory is for)...

Comment: ... instead, the dimension of a vector space is meant to capture the number of "directions" in which your lattice extends.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Thank you for that insight. This reminds me specifically of how we can write a vector space as the direct sum of a subspace and its orthogonal complement. And also the idea of dimension telling you the number of "directions" is very cool.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen By the way, is that sort of how we can think of (the dimension of a) quotient space? As like "how many more directions" we need in order to fill up the whole space?

Comment: @sigma2 more like „how many directions are left, if we ignore directions in the subspace“, but yes.